# Why is a dynamically instantiated component clipped?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am implementing a Timeline component whose bars can have tooltips. The Timeline component is used in another component that displays a list of these Timeline controls. In the below screenshot I have:

- Blue: List component
- Green: Timeline component
- Orange: Bar for which the tooltip is displayed
- Red: Tooltip component

The Timeline component is generated by a MatTable.

The Tooltip component is dynamically instantiated using a ComponentFactory. Its container (bar-tooltip-container) is “absolute” positioned.

As you can see for large tooltips, the tooltip is clipped at the grandparent boundary (List).

First, I am wondering why is it clipped? Then why it is not clipped a its parent level, at the Timeline boundary.

And finally, the question I have is how to make it to not clip the Tooltip.

Here you have the code: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timeline-with-tooltip) :

1. Make the run part on the right side larger so you see the timeline charts
2. Hover over any bar excepting excepting those for Driver 2-2 to see a normal tooltip
3. Hover over a bar belonging to Driver 2-2 to see a large tooltip
4. If you want the tooltip to stay so you can inspect it, go in src/app/timeline-row/timeline-row.component.ts and comment out lines 398-399

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the tooltip a library? Is it Material's one? How do you position the tooltip?

Comment: Tooltip is just a component that I implemented. The way I position it is getting the size of the tooltip container after it is rendered and then calculate the (left, top) coordinate. I am going to try to create a sample and add it to the question.

Comment: I updated the question to include a link to a StackBlitz repro.